# I would like to push a couple of arrays of data into a 2 dimensions array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to push a couple of columns of arrays into a 2 dimensions array in Javascript, adding one column in position 0 and the second column at the end of the array.

The initial array is something like this:

```
[[1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

The two arrays I would like to merge with the bidimensional array are:

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

and

```
[2,2,2,2]
```

The result should be the next:

```
[[0,1,1,1,2],
 [0,1,1,1,2],
 [0,1,1,1,2],
 [0,1,1,1,2]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Hi @Matias. In general, it's always good to show what you have tried yourself until now and what exactly didn't work.

Comment: Hey there, I've got already the answer I was looking for. Thank you, guys! I will keep in mind to add a chunk of code with the options I have tried in future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` and spread syntax to add elements to the front and end of each array.

```js
const arr = [[1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1]];
const start = [0], //supports adding multiple elements,
      end   = [2];
const res = arr.map(x => [...start, ...x, ...end]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Hi @iota, I have tried your code and it works perfectly when running it on the example I provided in the post. However, I noticed this map method does not work as expected in my code. I should have added a more detailed explanation with chunks of the real code.

Comment: @MatiasCarcamo Can you give an example of what doesn't work?

Comment: your suggestion works actually just fine. Apologies, I am new in the world of coding and it seems I made some mistakes when implementing your code. Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: @MatiasCarcamo No problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that the length of the arrays matches, this can also be solved with a loop as follows:

```
const arr = [[1,1,1],
             [1,1,1],
             [1,1,1],
             [1,1,1]];
const arrBeg = [0,0,0,0];
const arrEnd = [2,2,2,2];

arr.forEach(function (val, ix) {
    val.unshift(arrBeg[ix]);
    val.push(arrEnd[ix]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple `for` loop like this:

```
var arr = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
var arr1 = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var arr2 = [2, 2, 2, 2];

var arr1each = 0;
var arr2each = 0;
for (each = 0; each < arr.length; each++) {
  arr[each].unshift(arr1[arr1each]);
  arr[each].push(arr2[arr2each])
  arr1each++;
  arr2each++;
  continue;
}

console.log(arr)
```

[Here is Codepen](https://codepen.io/demiavaliani/pen/mdrLxoy)

Answer (score 0):

This is basic, but will do for what you want:

```
function alterArray() {
    var testArray = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]];
    testArray.forEach( arrayElement => {
        arrayElement.unshift(0);`
        arrayElement.push(2);})   
}
```

Comment: Hi @observer50, I tried your code and it works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  Actually. Val R.'s solution is the same as mine, but more elegantly done.